# React: sub.component not re-rendering on main.component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I just started studying React and I got into the following issue: the SubComponent doesn't re-render data when updating the state.

Main component is the view Webpage for holding all the subComponents, the Logic component manages all the functions and this one subComponent is a smaller HTML for rendering one of the functions.

MainComponent:

```
import LogicComponent from "./LogicComponent";
import SubComponent from "./SubComponent";
export default function Main() {
  const { getMaintenance } = LogicComponent()
  return (
  <>
    <div onclick={getMaintenance}>CLICK ME</div>
    <SubComponent/>
  </>
  )
}
```

LogicComponent:

```
export default function LogicComponent() {
   const [activeMaintenance, setActiveMaintenance] = useState([]);

   async function getMaintenance() {
     getDocs(collection(db, `/maintenance`))
     .then((response) => {
        setActiveMaintenance(
           response.docs.map((doc) => ({
              id: doc.id,
              ...doc.data(),
           }))
        );
     })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
     });
   }
   return {
      getMaintenance,
      activeMaintenance,
   }
}
```

SubComponent

```
import LogicComponent from "./LogicComponent";
export default function SubComponent() {
  const { activeMaintenance } = LogicComponent();
  return (
    <>
      {activeMaintenance.map((fileData) => (
        <div key={fileData.id}>{fileData.info}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Whenever the **CLICK ME** button gets triggered, the data doesn't update on the SubComponent, even if logged correctly into console.

If I put the SubComponent code into the MainComponent, it updates without issues.

・What I would like to know is, why does the SubComponent not re-render when the data is received?

Also, any React programming advice is more than welcome.

Comment: What is `ModifyLogic`? Why is `subComponent` lowercase in `Main`? Why is `LogicComponent` capitalized and labelled as a component when it's more of a state thing? Should be called `useActiveMaintenance`. And if you try calling it more than once (e.g. from different components) you're going to create multiple state objects, it won't be shared across.

Comment: Also, where are you getting `fileData` in your `SubComponent`?

Comment: @mpen ModifyLogic: miss spelled while transcribing the example. Lowercase typo for the SubComponent. I might need to study more the difference between the Component and State on React. Thanks for the call out on creating multiple state objects.

Comment: @Ed Lucas, fileData comes up when mapping the activeMaintenance data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

As mentioned in the comments, you have 2 instances of LogicComponent - one in SubComponent and one in Main. Think of this like having 2 instances of a class - the state kept within each is completely separate. When you call getMaintenance from Main, you update the state of the instance of LogicComponent kept within Main. SubComponent’s instance is not updated.

### Solution 1

The simplest possible change to make your current setup work is the following:

```js
function SubComponent({ activeMaintenance }) {
  return (
    <>
      {activeMaintenance.map((fileData) => (
        <div key={fileData.id}>{fileData.info}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

function Main() {
  const { getMaintenance, activeMaintenance } = LogicComponent();
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={getMaintenance}>CLICK ME</button>
      <SubComponent activeMaintenance={activeMaintenance} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Allow Main to house the one and only instance of LogicComponent, and pass activeMaintenance down to SubComponent as a prop. This is just a couple line change. Here is a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-hook-v2-8ixgvg?file=/src/App.js) (replacing your DB call with a phony promise).

### Solution 2

It seems like you are longing for a shared state, in which case you may want to look into [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Another note in the comments that deserves re-mentioning, you should consider renaming LogicComponent to useMaintenance, as it is essentially a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html).

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-hook-v1-zqu0so?file=/src/App.js) is a working CodeSandbox of what a simple shared global state  might look like for your App (using context & hooks).